# keydown not catching enter key

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke, keydown

I'm using the following jquery to catch the enter key being pressed so I can click a link (this is a workaround for a [DNN bug](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/logon-form-or-button-wont-respond-to-enter-key)):

```
var $container = $('div[id$="Login_DNN"]');

$container.keydown(function (event) {
    alert('key press = ' + event.which); //<--- This pops up for all keys but enter

    if(event.which===13){
        //This only works for modern browsers
        if (HTMLElement.prototype.click) {
            $container.find('a[id$="cmdLogin"]')[0].click();
        }
    };
});
```

It isn't working, though. I dropped an alert into the keydown function for testing and it correctly displays the key press for each key that I hit except for the one I really want, the enter key.

A simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmtxvuzw/) doesn't reproduce the issue. Why would this not work for me? Is the enter key being hijacked by something else?

Comment: Something else is catching it first, do you have a search box on the page?

Comment: @ChrisHammond - I didn't have a search box but you were essentially correct. I was able to correct the underlying issue by modifying the `\DesktopModules\AuthenticationServices\DNN\Login.ascx` file instead of using the code in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Other code was catching the enter key first

I ended up implementing a different solution I found elsewhere. Since this is a DNN bug, I went into `\DesktopModules\AuthenticationServices\DNN\Login.ascx` and replaced all instances of `<%#ModuleId%>` to `<%=ModuleId%>`. Then I moved the keypress check into its own function so it can be called on both `$(document).ready()` and on partial postback. Here's the full script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*globals jQuery, window, Sys */
    (function ($, Sys) {
        function setUpLogin() {
            var actionLinks = $("a#dnn_ctr<%=ModuleId > Null.NullInteger ? ModuleId.ToString() : ""%>_Login_Login_DNN_cmdLogin");
            actionLinks.click(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass("dnnDisabledAction"))

                { return false; }
                actionLinks.addClass("dnnDisabledAction");
            });
        }

        function setUpKeydown() {
            $('.dnnLoginService').on('keydown', function (e) {
                if ($(e.target).is('input:text,input:password') && e.keyCode === 13) {
                    var $loginButton = $('#dnn_ctr<%=ModuleId > Null.NullInteger ? ModuleId.ToString() : ""%>_Login_Login_DNN_cmdLogin');
                    if ($loginButton.hasClass("dnnDisabledAction"))

                    { return false; }
                    $loginButton.addClass("dnnDisabledAction");
                    eval($loginButton.attr('href'));
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            setUpKeydown(); 
            setUpLogin();

            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () {
                setUpKeydown(); setUpLogin();
            });
        });
    }(jQuery, window.Sys));
</script>
```